# Is there a central document store in Drupal 6 or a module that does?

Tags: nodes, 6

I have a content type in Drupal 6 that consists of 3 main fields, each allows for the upload of unlimited files, which I have restricted to being PDF or DOC based formats. Lets say there will 100 pieces of content based on this type. Whilst most of the uploads made, may well be unique, the customer has identified that there are a few docs, that may need to be uploaded to more than one piece of content.

This led on to the question regarding if there is a central document store of some kind in Drupal (especially 6 in this case). Such a tool would mean that files would only need to be uploaded once but referenced many times from various pieces of content.

Does anyone have any solutions to this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the [FileField Sources module](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) is exactly what you're looking for.

> FileField Sources is an extension to the FileField module. The
>   FileField module lets you upload files from your computer through a
>   CCK field. The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by
>   allowing you to select new or existing files through additional means,
>   including:
>
> - **Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield Attach server-side files**
> - uploaded via FTP Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> - Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only) Select
> - existing files through the IMCE file browser

Answer (score 2):

*All* uploaded documents in Drupal goes into the *same* directory (you identify this directory when you configure [files system settings](http://drupal.org/node/15368)).  This directory is the central document store you ask about.

As for allowing one uploaded file to be attached to multiple nodes, there is nothing in Drupal that stops you from doing this, but there is no UI for it in core (so without a module, you need to manipulate the DB directly).  However, the [File Framework](http://drupal.org/project/fileframework) module has an UI that lets you do this.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking is the [file_entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module in D7.

If you search around, it's possible you can find a similar back ported functionality, but I haven't seen it. Here's a blog post that discusses some alternatives: http://blog.merge.nl/2010/07/15/media-library-alternatives-drupal-6

You can emulate it in D6 by basically uploading each file into a node, and using node references as provided by CCK, but that's very bulky compared to file entities.